# DDD - How should I handle domain entities creation?

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

I'm currently migrating an existing api for routing, I'm trying to use DDD because is really complex, and the current code is a nightmare.
So lets say we have 3 entities, route, trip-request, driver and vehicle, here are some facts regarding this entities:

- Route has the following structure, route->activity[]->activity->payload[]->payload.requestId
- A Request belongs to 1 route
- Route can have multiple requests, and those requests can be duplicated within the same route (a pickup payload and delivery payload will share the same request)
- Some actions on the route will modify the request, starting a route will also start the request
- Some actions on the request will modify the route, like cancelling a request may or may not cancel a route
- A vehicle can be used for multiple routes
- A Route will have 1 vehicle
- A Driver is basically a user
- A Route will have 1 driver

With this in mind these are my questions:

Regarding route-request relationship..

- So I think Route and Request are 2 Aggregates Roots and the interaction between this two would be through domain events, I came to this conclusion because I do not see any other way to model this relationship, what do you think of this?

In the case of route-vehicle, so the RouteAR has a reference to the vehicle, you can create a route without a vehicle and assign it later, so we will have a method setVehicle(vehicleId)

- How will the RouteAR get the vehicle data? the RouteAR is not supposed to access the DAL
- Vehicles can be shared in different routes, so the vehicle domain class should be part of the route aggregrate, if this is true how do I create a new Vehicle? Vehicles are currently created outside the context of a route, and domain objects are not supposed to be shared across aggregates

In the case of route-driver relationship, The user is created outside of the boundaries of route aggregate,

- but same as with the vehicle, I should have a setDriver(driverId) or setDriver(driverData), where am I supposed to get the driver data from the db if the routeAR does not have data access capabilities

EDIT After the response

So I've been moving forward with this, now, the main problem I'm having is that I do not fully see how the relationship should be, a Route and Request, they have their own lifecycle (each one have have its own workflow, like route, scheduled...), but the actions that you take on each other in many cases will modify the other entity, a few examples...

- if you cancel the request it will modify the route, since the route needs to be re-calculated, and depending on the state of the route, is the action that you will be doing on the request upon cancellation.
- when you start a route you also start the request,
- when a route is completed all the requests are completed

So there are certain operations like starting a route that will start with a route Id only, there are some other operations like cancelling a request that will start with a requestId only, and there are some other operations where you will start with a routeId, and a couple of requestId.

This looks like two separate aggregates, so I started using events to go back and forth between the two aggregates root, but there are a lot fo events going on and does not seem like an scalable solution.

In the case of a lets say creating a new Delivery AR, there is not Delivery entity in the system so how would this look like? I mean the Delivery repository should load what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that it is preferred you ask just one question per SO entry.

> So I think Route and Request are 2 Aggregates Roots and the interaction between this two would be through domain events, I came to this conclusion because I do not see any other way to model this relationship, what do you think of this?

One way to verify this is to think about lifetimes. Do these two Aggregates get created independently of each other? It sounds like the answer is 'yes'. So then the next question is, how do you manage the relationship between these two. Typically, interactions between Aggregates are managed by Process Managers/Sagas and one way to do that is via events.

You might also consider modeling the relationship between a Request and a Route as an Aggregate, e.g. Delivery. A Delivery might capture that relationship in a way that can allow you to manage the lifetime of that relationship. What happens, for example, if a Request is removed from a Route? Should that be a first-class concept in your domain model?

> How will the RouteAR get the vehicle data? the RouteAR is not supposed to access the DAL

The Route Aggregate should not access your DAL. I might argue it shouldn't need anything beyond a RequestId or PayloadId to do it's actual work. Those Ids or the entire Request Aggregate can be provided by a Domain Service to your Route Aggregate. Also, keep in mind the difference between an Aggregate Root and Aggregate since you seem to be using them interchangeably here.

> how do I create a new Vehicle?

Creating a new Vehicle exists outside of the scope of the Route Aggregate. Your Route Aggregate can refer to a Vehicle by Id. I don't see why you might be creating a new representation of a Vehicle for each Route.

> where am I supposed to get the driver data from the db if the routeAR does not have data access capabilities

As above, you would have a Domain Service that would load the User, ensure that your request is valid from a Domain perspective and then pass the UserId to your Route Aggregate. Very simple code sample for Domain Service below. It ignores idempotency, double booking, checking for existence of Route/Driver, etc.

```cs
public void AssignDriverToRoute(RouteId routeId, DriverId driverId)
{
    // This is domain logic, not DataAccess
    var driver = driverRepository.Load(driverId);
    var route = routeRepository.Load(routeId);
    if (driver.Active == false)
    {   
        throw new InvalidRouteDriverException(routeId, driverId);
    }
    route.AssignDriver(driverId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to process it and get back if I have further questions

Comment: I have edited the post based on your response, thanks a lot man